# using sed to convert camelCase to under_score

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

I have a sed script that can convert camelCase to under_score which works great for this example:

```
myvar="camelCase"
converted="$(echo $myvar | sed 's/\([A-Z]\)/_\L\1/g;s/^_//')"

echo converted
// result: camel_case
```

However, I have the following case:

```
myvar="camelCASE"
converted="$(echo $myvar | sed 's/\([A-Z]\)/_\L\1/g;s/^_//')"

echo converted
// result: camel_c_a_s_e
```

The result I need in this particular case is: camel_case.

to be clear, the final sed script should work for "camelCase" as well as "camelCASE", and "CAMELcase".

myvar shall never contain special characters or spaces

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28795479/awk-sed-script-to-convert-a-file-from-camelcase-to-underscores

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416656/underscore-to-camelcase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that your `\([A-Z]\)` only captures a single uppercase letter at a time. To fix that in POSIX BRE sed, you can use `\([A-Z]\{1,\}\)` ex.

```
$ echo camelCASE | sed 's/\([A-Z]\{1,\}\)/_\L\1/g;s/^_//'
camel_case
```

At least in GNU sed, ou can avoid the special treatment of leading `_` by only matching after a non-wordbreak

```
$ echo CamelCASE | sed 's/\B\([A-Z]\{1,\}\)/_\L\1/g'
Camel_case
```

It's slightly more readable in ERE

```
$ echo CamelCASECamelCase | sed -E 's/\B([A-Z]+)/_\L\1/g'
Camel_casecamel_case
```

or even (using `&` instead of the explicit grouping)

```
$ echo CamelCASECamelCase | sed -E 's/\B[A-Z]+/_\L&/g'
Camel_casecamel_case
```

Comment: picking this one as correct answer as its a nice clean 1-liner (for the posix version)

Comment: @Thomas Smart : Marked as a good answer but this does not work... Try the first `echo ... | sed ...` with a more complicated string like CamelCASECamelCase and youll see

Comment: it worked for my situation at the time and the stated usecase which did not have such complex examples. in that regard, it answered the question. i do agree that the other answer is better for a broader range of scenarios that others might have.

Answer (score 7):

You must consider that case change is the mark of a word. Space `_` have to be placed just before the case change

Try this :

```
$ echo 'CamelCASECamelCase' \
| sed 's/\([^A-Z]\)\([A-Z0-9]\)/\1_\2/g' \
| sed 's/\([A-Z0-9]\)\([A-Z0-9]\)\([^A-Z]\)/\1_\2\3/g' \
| tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'

# will output this
camel_case_camel_case
```

Comment: This is the only answer I've found that also works on mac os

Comment: @micimize : yes the answer from steeldriver does not work, he did not test it enough